# ios segue unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, segue, unrecognized-selector

I'm working on an iOS app and I've encountered a problem during testing: the app crashes when I try to enter my next ViewController and I get these messages:

```
2014-06-29 14:22:46.674 IOS2 Practica[55472:60b] -[Logger login:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9242230
2014-06-29 14:22:46.679 IOS2 Practica[55472:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Logger login:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9242230'
```

From other cases I've looked up, it might be possible that something happens when I attempt to use "segue" to switch to the next ViewController but I can't pinpoint the exact source.

I append the code segment where I define the segue in my main View Controller:

```
- (void)logger:(id)sender {
    NSString *user = self.username.text;
    NSString *pass = self.password.text;

    NSString * urlBase = @"http://www.v2msoft.com/clientes/lasalle/curs-ios/login.php?username=lluis&password=seguro";

    [JSONHTTPClient getJSONFromURLWithString:urlBase completion:^(id json,JSONModelError *err){

        JsonUser * user = [[JsonUser alloc]initWithDictionary:json error:nil];

        if(user.succeed) {
            self.user_id = user.user_id;

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Login" sender:self];
         } else {
             NSLog(@"error");
        }
     }];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if (_username.text.length == 0 || _password.text.length == 0) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                    message:@"Algun dels camps és incorrecte o està buit!"
                                   delegate:self
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]
         show];

    } else {
        Supermarket * supermercat = segue.destinationViewController;
        supermercat.user_id = self.user_id;
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance for any insight on this topic.

Comment: Do you have a segue set up in the storyboard with the identifier "Login"?

Comment: Yes. First thing I checked. I have the segues and I did check that the names match. So that's not it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your code (not the bit you posted), you should be calling a `login:` method on a `Logger` instance. That method is not defined in `Logger` and that is why the app crashes.

Pay attention to the `:` at the end of `Login:`: possibly you have defined a `login` method (which does not take any argument), but you are calling it with an argument. Or maybe you would have liked to call `logger:`.

You can try 2 things out: either you find out where the `login:` method is called (some button bound to it in Storyboard?) or you rename `logger:` into `login:`.